# How to modify the TypeConverter so I can parse complex data in Room with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, typeconverter

I have a data object like this one, that I use to save data into a column in Room.

```
data class MyObject(val list1: List<String>)
```

So if the data Class has this data MyObject(listOf(“A”,”B”,”C”))

The data for that column will be saved like this in column #1

[image]

Now I need to add data to that object and therefore to the column, new object looks like this

```
data class MyObject(val list1: List<String>,
                         val list2: List<String>,
                         val list3: List<String>,
                         val isEnabled: Boolean,
                         val isDone: Boolean)
```

I don´t know how to modify the TypeConverter so I can parse complex data, current Converter is this

```
class MyObjectConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToMyObject (value: String?): MyObject? {
        return value?.let {
            MyObject (it.split(","))
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun myObjectToString(myObject: MyObject?): String? {
        return myObject?.value?.joinToString(",")
    }
}
```

Comment: To make this work, you will need a `TypeConverter` that uses something more sophisticated to serialize and deserialize your data. For example, you could use a JSON parser (Moshi, Gson, etc.) to convert your object to and from string representations. However, you might consider getting rid of Room and just saving your data in JSON files. It is unclear to me what value you are getting out of Room, if most of your data is all being crammed into one column.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare  this is a Project already in place, I cannot get rid of Room. Also, I don´t want to save the data for that column on JSON format, I need it in string format.

Comment: JSON *is* a string format.

Comment: I know that, I mean, i don´t want the JSON formatted string, I need something like this "A,B,C/R,S,T/Z,F,T/true/false" or like this "[A,B,C],[R,S,T],[Z,F,T],[true],[false]"

Comment: I agree with @CommonsWare - if you don't need relationships between any tables then your choice of storing your data structures (`List` types with n number of items) currently doesn't make sense in a database in the current way. I'm not sure its fair to say you "cannot" change it. It might be a cost now, because current code doesn't separate concerns well and/or not planned for - but surely over time you'll put yourself down a larger rabbit hole if your don't address this now correctly.

Comment: Guys, I appreciate the time and guidance, but the question is clear. There is a need to be solve.  changing the architecture or using another libraries is not a solution

Comment: "I need something like this "A,B,C/R,S,T/Z,F,T/true/false" or like this "[A,B,C],[R,S,T],[Z,F,T],[true],[false]"" -- then hand-roll your own parser and serializer for that format. Use the parser in your `stringToMyObject()` function. Use the serializer in your `myObjectToString()` function.

Comment: If you are uncertain how to generate one of those strings from a `MyObject`, and how to generate a `MyObject` from one of those strings, that would be a better as a separate question. Room has nothing to do with that, nor Android. That is a pure Kotlin question, and you would have better luck asking it separately in the `kotlin` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The converter should be for the `List<String>` not for `MyObject`, that way room will use the converter only for the fields it can't persist out of the box. the converter would look like this:

```
class MyListConverter {

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToList (value: String?): List<String>? {
        return value?.split(",")
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun listToString(list: List<String>?): String? {
        return list?.joinToString(",")
    }
}
```

use this with `MyObject` room entity and it would be used for the first three fields in `MyObject`, while the other two `Boolean` fields can be handled by room.